# AWS- Using dependency for third party SDK with lambdas?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to use cron via CloudWatch to run a simple python script that utilizes a third party API to check for an available number.  My goal is to have CloudWatch run the cron, trigger a lambda that runs the python script, if there is a number returned to trigger an SNS notification.

My problem is installing the third party API dependencies.  I am getting an error of the module not found.  Can third party dependencies be used with lambdas or am I better off installing them on an EC2 instance I manually spin up?

Comment: Are you packaging up the third-party libraries into your Lambda function's deployment file?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mark.  I have installed the dependencies locally to one file, zipped that file and uploaded to match the handler.  Is there a particular way the deployment file needs to be configured?  Getting the following error:

`START RequestId: 4bb1d74f-52e0-4c04-b0b4-10faa5358251 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named vivialconnect`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

This goes over how to create a deployment package and include dependencies for python.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Working on getting the AWS CLI downloaded and having issues with an anaconda install from a while ago.  Getting the following error:  bad interpreter: No such file or directory.  Note:  I am following this documentation:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

Comment: @kefa could you share the code. That will help with troubleshooting the cause of the error.

Comment: Sorry for my delay, Hans.  Here is the error I am seeing after adding the AWS CLI executable to my MacOS command line as seen in the link above

`/Users/(myusername)/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`